# Does the verb "pick on" always have the unfair connotation to it?

Tags: word-meaning

According to one definition of "pick on", it's,

> repeatedly single (someone) out for criticism or unkind treatment in a
>   way perceived to be unfair.

[pick on meaning](http://repeatedly%20single%20(someone)%20out%20for%20criticism%20or%20unkind%20treatment%20in%20a%20way%20perceived%20to%20be%20unfair.)

But another translation I get to Spanish it's

> meddle with someone

one has a connotation of being unfair, and the other doesnt, though, in translations, sometimes part of the meaning is lost.

Does the verb "pick on" always have the unfair connotation to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "pick on [someone]" does usually imply that you have singled them out for treatment, eg:

> The teacher repeatedly picked on John.

If you mean to simply select someone, we just use "pick":

> The teacher repeatedly picked John to answer the questions.